# Problem with SetCapture and IWebBrowser2 container

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, com

I have an OLE object of IWebBrowser2 wrapped in a window.

At some point I expand the window and its OLE object and I'd like it to collapse on external click (i.e. every click that is outside the web browser).

I use `SetCapture` on the window wrapper but from some reason, during the capture,  the Webbrowser doesn't receive any mouse events (clicks,move etc...)

Any thoughts\ideas?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cite from [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Sets the mouse capture to the specified window belonging to the
>   current thread. SetCapture captures mouse input either when the mouse
>   is over the capturing window, or **when the mouse button was pressed** 
>   **while the mouse was over the capturing window and the button is still** 
>   **down**. Only one window at a time can capture the mouse.

So you cannot use `SetCapture` on a window to actually capture clicks. It specifically for the case where the user clicks your window and moves the mouse out, while keeping the button pressed. So you will have to use another mechanism.